# API tests server side vs. functional tests

Tags: api, rest, testing

What are some of the server side tests that can be performed on REST based APIs . Are  functional tests on API considered server side tests? I was trying to search but couldn't get any direct related answers so thought of asking here. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
As per suggestion/answer from inf3rno below I am adding more info so its easy to answer.

1) how to do functional API tests on server side and how to automate them.What other functional test we can do beside the ones suggested by inf3rno.

2) types of unit test that can be done on APIs.

3) any security tests that can be done.

Appreciate any input here. Thanks.

Comment: What type of tests are you looking for? You can do e2e tests by following the links the service provides e.g. with nightwatch or jasmine-jquery in javascript. I think this is recommended, because the code of the tests can be reused to build automated clients. By onioin/ports&adapters/etc... so by architectures with a domain model, you can mock out the domain model and the HTTP framework, and run integration tests on the REST API part in isolation. You can unit test e.g. the link generation etc... So I don't think there are any special things involved here...

Comment: @inf3rno Thank you for responding. That was helpful. It cleared some thoughts and gave me some points . 1) how to do functional API tests on server side and how to automate them and 2) kind of unit test that can be performed with APIs. I was looking that kind of answer. Please let me know if there are other kind on test that can be performed. for ex: any security related tests , any other type of unit  test. Basically i asked this ques from an interview view point. I am a test engineer. Thank you again for your input.

Comment: I think you should add these details to your question and maybe somebody, who has more experience, will answer it.